# Why does jQuery say my ajax jsonp call is failing?

Tags: jquery, jsonp

Not sure what I'm missing here, if you take a look at this code - you'll see I'm making a jsonp call to flickr and getting a successful response. However, jQuery always calls the 'fail' method and not the success method.

Why?

{{ EDITED }}

```
$.ajax({
      url: 'http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?format=json&tags=fun&tagmode=any',
      dataType: 'jsonp'
  })
  .done(function(data, status) {
    console.log( 'data count:', data.query.results.json.json.length );
    $('#result-count').text( JSON.stringify(data.query.results.json.json) );
  })
  .fail(function(xhr, err) {
    console.log( 'Sample of error data:', err );
    console.log("readyState: "+xhr.readyState+"\nstatus: "+xhr.status+"\nresponseText: "+xhr.responseText); });
  });
```

Comment: Why `async:false`? That's what the `A` in `AJAX` stands for!

Answer (score 2):

It's failing because you're using the wrong jsonp callback.

```
...
type: 'GET',
jsonpCallback: 'jsonFlickrFeed'
...
```

also, in recent versions of jQuery, jsonp requests don't trigger a `fail` callback on error, `async:false` is ignored for jsonp requests, and `crossDomain` is not necessary (jquery sets that for you).

Comment: Hi, yeh, I was trying to change the callback function name, but I see how that couldn't work. So if flickr is returning a valid jsonp response, then why does the FAIL callback always get called?

Comment: I don't know, what does the third argument tell you? what are you getting in the console? All of the information is right there in your browser, you've just got to access it. `console.log(arguments)` inside of `.fail`, it will give you 3 arguments, the third will most likely be "parseerror" indicating the returned jsonp wasn't what jQuery expected it to be. However, it may not be very useful due to the nature of how jsonp requests are sent. If it's failing, you really should be getting a javascript error in your console.

Comment: Ahh, yep, Thanks Kevin B. I'm still not clear why the Fail method is getting called. The response is 200. The status is 4, success. So I'm not sure why. It works, it's just not working as I expected.